# Querying a view in SQL through Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am trying to query an already existing view in SQL Server which I am connected to in Visual Studio 2019.

I've created a class corresponding to the name of my Users database called `UsersDbContext`.:

```
 class UsersDbContext : DbContext
    {            
        public DbSet<EventView> Users { get; set; }
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"Data Source=REDACTED;User ID=REDACTED;Password=REDACTERD;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False");
        }
    }
```

In this database I have a view named `eventview.fss`.
How do I access the data from here from Entity Framework?

In my main class where I want to process the data:

```
private static readonly UsersDbContext _context = new UsersDbContext();

var myid = _context.Users.FromSqlRaw($"SELECT Id FROM eventview.fss");
```

In my models class I've added a model for the view. It is very simple:

```
public class EventView
{
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

What am I missing? Ideally I'd like to have the the rows from the view be put into a `List<EventView>` then I can work with the data from there.

Edit: when I try to run `_context.Users.FromSqlRaw($"SELECT Id FROM eventview.fss").ToList();` I get the error for SqlException: Invalid object name eventview.fss

Answer (score 2):

You can tell EF Core how to retrieve the data set so you don't need to use raw sql. Add a dbset in the context. In OnModelCreating, something like:
builder.Entity().HasNoKey().ToView("eventview.fss", "YourSchemaName");

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that my connection string was missing the `Database` property. Once I've added it now I can pull the data.